# Why does my custom Python enumerator type cause an error in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I define a custom type that I use as an enumerator in Python.

```
# enums.py

def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

UserType = enum(
    USER=1,
    POWER=2,
    ADMIN=3
)
```

I use the enumerator as below:

```
from my_app import enums

if user.type_id == enums.UserType.ADMIN:
    print "User is Admin"
```

The code works perfectly as expected, but the interperator is giving me the below error:
[image]

`Undefined variable from import: ADMIN`

Anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In my env, it is running correctly.

Maybe the reason is that python is weak typed language, so the complier does not know whether enums.UserType has attribute 'ADMIN', so it gives error. But in the run-time env, it's OK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you using eclipse on Windows?

Comment: Yeah, I used PyDev plugin of eclipse on Windows years ago. But now changed to PYcharm, it's really charming, and worth a try.